# Change the characters in mysql with Convert failing - Still getting NÃ£o

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I am populating this mysql table with data from a php (via post and using filter_input).
The database is utf8 but when I have a user that inputs words with ^,',',~ like Não I get this -> NÃ£o

What do I have to do to make it show the correct values. Or should I try to make some correction when I retrieve the data??

UPDATE:

I have added a utf8_decode and now it is inserting ok. 
Anyone know how to convert the string that were already in the table?? I tried using the convert function but I can't make it work :(

UPDATE:

I am trying this code:

> select convert(field using latin1)
>   from table where id = 35;

And I am still getting this: NÃ£o
I tried other encoding s but I never get the word Não

Anyone have any thoughts on this one??

Comment: Where are these characters? Is this what it displays in the actual database view (like in phpmyadmin), or when you pull data from the database and display it on a page?

Comment: This is from the database. I am using heidisql

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your page is utf-8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

next, if your on Apache, make sur your in UTF-8 in config file :

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

or your can do it in a .php file like this :

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

if you still have problem, you can use the encode function :

```
$value = utf8_encode($value);
```

Hope all this will help...

Comment: I also tried changing the header but with no luck I am still getting does weird chars

Comment: You should change the order: first HTTP header than META tag. Otherwise the HTTP header will override the META tag.

Comment: Just to know, if you simply do echo ("Não"); Do you have Não or something else on the screen ??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like somewhere along the way something cannot handle Unicode. As a result, ã is getting interpreted as two separate characters. Make sure everything that handles strings is OK with Unicode.